# Can't centre navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, nav

I've looked at so many questions of people asking how to centre a navigation bar, and I've tried lots of things and just cannot get it to move...

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <h1>Midlands Car Club</h1>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="members.php" title="Members">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="cars.php" title="Cars">Cars</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
//header
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
}

#header h1{
font-family: "Vernada", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.8em;
text-align: center;
}

//navigation
#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

#nav a {
display: inline-block;
width: 80px;
background-color: #dddddd;
text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
display: inline;
color: black;
font-family: "Vernada", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
}

#nav a:link {
width: 120px;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

#nav a:visited {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

#nav a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: grey;
}

#nav a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: blue;
}
```

Most likely missed something out, or just gone about it wrong altogether. I've managed to get it working in the past but have completely forgotten how I did it...

Comment: Also it's recommend not to use id selectors (#) in css and instead use classnames. So #nav becomes .nav and <ul id="nav"> becomes <ul class="nav">

Comment: Next time, please make a fiddle for us to work in ;) https://jsfiddle.net/ymhhvtd6/

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav {
    width : "however wide you want it";
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It's the margin: 0 auto; that centers the element.

You could also use text-align on the parent element, but the margin trick is most commonly used.